# Why a `atomic_signal_fence` is used here when getting system time

Tags: c++, concurrency, atomic, barrier

I found this function in a [github repo](https://github.com/cameron314/concurrentqueue) which implements a lockfree queue. This function uses the `QueryPerformanceCounter` to get accurate system time.

```
#define CompilerMemBar() std::atomic_signal_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst)
SystemTime getSystemTime()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER t;
    CompilerMemBar();
    if (!QueryPerformanceCounter(&t)) {
        return static_cast<SystemTime>(-1);
    }
    CompilerMemBar();

    return static_cast<SystemTime>(t.QuadPart);
}
```

I noticed there are two `CompilerMemBar()`, which I thought is intented to prevent compiler from re-ordering. However, after I searched some codes on github, I found wrapping `QueryPerformanceCounter` with compiler barriers may not be a common practice. So my question is these barriers here to handle some special situations? May be a possible reorder will affect the precision of system time we get? But I can't figure out how they will do, because I think even either the WINAPI call or the return statement is reordered, it seems to have no influence on the precision.

Comment: fyi: Lots for caveats here regarding older systems and `QueryPerformanceCounter` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408(v=vs.85).aspx  Could this possibly be an attempt at a fix/workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code developer may have believed that it would produce more accurate results if the compiler could not reorder statements..
For example:

```
expensive1(); // takes a lot of time

SystemTime t = getSystemTime();

expensive2();
```

If you want the exact timestamp (or performance count) in between both expensive calls, you don't want the compiler to reorder `getSystemTime()` with one of them
because it might have impact on the value returned by `QueryPerformanceCounter`.

Whether that is realistic, I don't know. The compiler has to know what is happening inside the function or it won't reorder anything
(if the `expensive` calls are defined in a pre-compiled library, no reordering of statements will take place anyway).

But at least this approach does not seem to do much harm.
`std::atomic_signal_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst)` prevents the compiler from reordering, but it does not produce CPU fence instructions.